# The inclusion $G^s\subset C^\infty$ is strict

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I'm studying the [Gevrey class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class) $G^s,\;s>1$, which is a subset of the $C^\infty$ class. I want to find an example of a function that is $C^\infty$ but not $G^s$.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Borel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) to find a function $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$$
g^{(j)}(0)=j!^{j}.
$$
It's then clear this function can't be $G^s(\mathbb{R})$ for any $s$.

Comment: Exactly! I'm familiar with Borel's theorem and  this is a good example. Thanks.

Comment: @JemY, if you find this a good example, then you should accept it.